# Spaces in file path in java

Tags: java, space, filepath

I have a folder which contains few jar files.  I am referring to those jar files from another jar file which is in some other location.

My problem is, when I give the path of the jar folder like this `C:\Trial Library\jar Folder\` ie. with space in the folder names (Trial Library) then it is unable to locate this folder.

If I give without space ie `C:\Trial_Library\jar_Folder\` then it works fine.

Please help me to fix this issue ASAP.

Here is my Batch File

```
set CURRENT_DIRECTORY=%~dp0

set ANT_HOME=%"CURRENT_DIRECTORY"%ant\apache-ant-1.8.3
ECHO current directory is %CURRENT_DIRECTORY%
ECHO %ANT_HOME%
set Path=%ANT_HOME%\bin
set ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH=%1
set USER_JAR_PATH=%2
set CLASS_NAME=%3
set RESULTS_PATH=%4
set JUNIT_PATH=%"CURRENT_DIRECTORY"%ANT\test\junit-4.1.jar
set LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE="%JUNIT_PATH%";"%ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%";"%USER_JAR_PATH%"
ECHO %LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE%
ECHO %ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%
ECHO %JUNIT_PATH%
ECHO %USER_JAR_PATH%
ECHO %CLASS_NAME%
ECHO %RESULTS_PATH% 

ant -lib "%LIBRAIES_TO_INCLUDE%" -Dlibraries="%ADAPTER_LIBRAY_PATH%" -Djunitlibrary="%JUNIT_PATH%" -Djartobeexec="%USER_JAR_PATH%" -Duserclass=%CLASS_NAME% -Dresultspath=%RESULTS_PATH% -buildfile build.xml test-html
```

Here is where i pass the values to my batch file

```
String[] commands=new String[5];
commands[0]="driver.bat";
commands[1]=finalLibraryPath;
commands[2]=executingJarLocation;
commands[3]=tempPackageName;
commands[4]=resultsFolderPath;
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands); 
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuffer errorStr = new StringBuffer(); 
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
errorStr.append(line);
errorStr.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));  

}
```

Thanx in advance

Regards,
Prabhu

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from what I understand I'm "guessing" that you are doing something like

```
Runtime.exec("myBatchFile.bat " + path);
```

This will end in tears.  This is the equivalent of saying:

```
C:> myBatchFile.bat C:\Path to my jar files
```

This won't work.  Basically, your batch file now thinks it has 5 parameters instead of one.

To fix the problem you need to pass each command/parameter seperatly...

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] {"mybatchFile.bat", path});
```

Or better still, use `ProcessBuilder`

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myBatchFile.bar", path);
```

Comment: Programmer:Finally i found out the issue.There is no issue in passing the parameters to the batch file.I added %~s1 in my library path in the batch file which removes space and adds ~1 which understandable by ant.Now it working fine.Thanks man for helping me.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of running about :P - Glad we got a solution in the end

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the path in quotes. This means that the computer takes it literally. You can have a similar problem with notepad, where it adds a `.txt` extension on the end even if you supply the extension. Wrapping in quotes solves this problem.

Comment: i m getting the path and storing it in the string and then only i m passing it to the service layer for processing ie)String samplePath="C:\Trial Library\jar Folder".is this what u r trying to say?

Comment: No, the quotes there just say its a string. try this: String samplepath = "\"C:\Trial Library\jar Folder\""

Comment: the value of the string is not hard coded .ie) i have like String samplePath=request.getParameter(jarPath); Please do help me in solving this.

Answer (score -2):

Generally enclosing the path in double quotes ("path") works on platforms like Unix, Linux etc. 
The problem only comes on WIN platform. The reason behind this is that as soon as the WIN sees a space in the path of a file to be executed, it reverts to 8.3 naming. In this naming, it takes the first 6 characters of the Sub directory as the param and searches for the pattern.
To solve the issue, you have to append the first 6 characters with a tilde(~) and a number representing the instance of that pattern.

For ex:

**Original PATH :  C:/Program Files/Jdk1.6.0_07/bin

PATH to be used : C:/Progra~1/Jdk1.6.0_07/bin**

I have used the similar approach in lots of my Java applications and it has worked correctly all of the times.

Comment: This is 1) incorrect; Windows handles paths with spaces exactly the same way others do: if you enclose it in spaces when as an argument, it is taken as a single argument. Someone even posted that here already... over two years ago. 2) This was not the issue in this question.

Comment: try it out dude... U can refer to following link [link](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=175536) for more explanations and if the windows would have handled the pathnames in the same way , then similar kind of questions would not have come in the forum.

Comment: Not sure you read that link very well. It says exactly what I said: Enclose them in double-quotes. The *only* difference mentioned there is that Unixes accept *single* quotes, also. Windows does not. And yes; you could use the 8.3 path too. But your assertion that Windows doesn't handle quoting is wrong. And still; it's not the issue here.