# Execute batch file through java, passing file path as arguments which contains space

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying update the classpath, in batch file by providing library location.

I am calling bat file through java, by passing library location as a arguments,
my code executes perfectly if there is no space in library path location,
If library path contains space, bat file throws exception, could not find or load a main class

below is my code

```
public class TestBat {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start",
    "C:\\Users\\graymatter\\Desktop\\MyBatch.bat",
    "D:\\Testing\\Main Plan");
  pb.start();
 }
}
```

This code executes perfect, 
If path has "D:\Testing\MainPlan", insted of "D:\Testing\Main Plan"

Here is my bat file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set DIR1=%1
echo %DIR1%
set CLASSPATH=.
FOR %%F IN ("%DIR1%"\lib\*.jar) DO (set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%F)

java -cp %CLASSPATH% com.pentaho.support.TestBat %*
```

So as per my knowledge am getting this error because of that space in path,
I tried a lot, by using escape sequence,
but no use.

Even referred @ [Spaces in file path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191302/spaces-in-file-path-in-java)

Thanks

Comment: *"Any quick help is appreciated"*  This discourages people from helping, on the basis that a question is 'too localized'.  I have resisted voting to close on the basis that the rest of the question seems well thought out, well researched and well presented.  But I suggest you remove that part.  It makes little difference anyway.  If people can help, they'll help as soon as they are able.

Comment: Please try `java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" com.pentaho.support.TestBat %*`; note the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If the argument contains spaces, it needs to be quoted. Use  `"\"D:\\Testing\\Main Plan\""`

The batch file should look

```
@echo off
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

  set "DIR1=%~1"
  echo %DIR1%
  set CLASSPATH=.
  FOR %%F IN ("%DIR1%\lib\*.jar") DO (set "CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%F")

  java -cp "%CLASSPATH%" com.pentaho.support.TestBat %*
```

Where `%~1` represent the first argument to batch file without quotes if it has any. Then, all the variable read/set are enclosed in quotes to handle any problem whith spaces.